# Как сделать вывод координат мыши, только если она попадает в определённую область

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, gui, if

Необходимо, чтобы координаты мыши выводились только тогда, когда происходит нажатие на мышь в определённой зоне (допустим зона имеет форму квадрата.)

Сделал небольшой код, но почему-то условие `if` не срабатывает.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
x=0
y=0

def getorigin(event):
      global x,y
      
      
      if (x>=0 or x<=100) and (y>=0 or y<=100):
           x = event.x
           y = event.y
        
           print(x,y)

          
root.bind("<Button-1>",getorigin)


#Добавим изображение
canvas = Canvas(root, height=800, width=800)
image = Image.open("zoo1.jpg")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
image = canvas.create_image(0, 0,image=photo,anchor='nw')
VOL1=canvas.create_oval(0,0,100,100)

    
canvas.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
x = None
y = None

def getorigin(event):
    global x, y
      
    x = event.x                                                             # !!!
    y = event.y                                                             # !!!
      
#      if (x >= 0 or x <= 100) and (y >= 0 or y <= 100):
    if (0 <= x <= 100) and (0 <= y <= 100):                                 # !!!
        print(f'Вы попали в квадрат (0, 0) - (100, 100). X = {x}, Y = {y}')
          
root.bind("<Button-1>",getorigin)

#Добавим изображение
canvas = Canvas(root, height=800, width=800)
image = Image.open("lena.jpg")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
image = canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=photo, anchor='nw')
VOL1=canvas.create_oval(0, 0, 100, 100, outline="yellow", fill="#125B50", width=2)
    
canvas.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]